# Injective functions have no functional extrema

Tags: functions

Is it true that all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that are injective (one-to-one) have no functional extrema? I can't find any counterexample, but that can easily be proved when we have a monotonic function.

Comment: Continuous injective functions? Or arbitrary injective functions? Continuous injective functions are necessarily monotonic.

Comment: @RobArthan Arbitrary injective ones, not continuous.

Comment: Small suggestion on English usage: the word you want for "everywhere increasing" is "monotone" or "monotonic" rather than 'monotonous.' "Monotonous", in English, is largely reserved to describe things that are boringly the same, like "sitting and waiting 14 hours for the connecting flight at Heathrow" or "having to listen to that fellow tell you about every single stroke of his golf game."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a specific example. Take
$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
   \arctan(x) & \mbox{if $x \neq \pm 1$} \\
   \pi/2 & \mbox{if $x = -1$} \\
   -\pi/2 & \mbox{if $x = 1$}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

No. If you take a bijection $$\phi : \Bbb{R} \to [0,1]$$ (a lot of them exist, but they are not continuous) and compose this with the inclusion map $$i: [0,1] \to \Bbb{R}$$ then you get $f=i \circ \phi$ is injective and attains its maximum and minimum.

Comment: What is the inclusion map? What are the final composition's maxima and minima? I am sorry to bother you, but I don't have such advanced knowledge...

Comment: The inclusion map for $[0, 1]$ just means the map with $i(x) = x$ for $x \in [0, 1]$. You might find it simpler to understand if $\phi$ is only required to be an injection. See my answer for a specific example along these lines with $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ in place of $[0, 1]$.